# How can i maintain Wifi connection state in Windows RT?

Tags: c#, networking, windows-8, alljoyn

I am developing a `Windows RT app`. I require the ***wifi*** to maintain it's connection state regardless of it's power saving preference since I'm implementing `Qualcomm's Alljoyn library`.
If the connection state changes, the p2p connection will be terminated.

How can I keep a certain state like **`Android's WIFI_MODE_FULL`**. I browsed through the MSDN but couldn't find any enlightment.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there's no direct way to do this, but you may do a workaround. The same that was made for WP7: stream an empty mp3 file from a server. That way the mediaplayer will take care of keeping the Wi-Fi on, but it drains some more battery.